# Error 429 Cannot create object when calling C# from VB6

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I've developed a simple class library in C# and want to expose his methods and variables to be referenced via COM Interop from VB6

The C# solution is released with COM Enabled, + Interface + GUID identifiers in the assembly files and also the interface and the unique function.

When I add the TLB file generated after release, the VB6 IDE links the file very well and I can see methods and properties at design time however when I executed the code I get the error #429 "Cannot create the ActiveX Object"

I tried to register the DLL file with command 'regasm', 'gacutil' and still cannot run methods of the DLL file from VB6 (C# Class Library)

AssemblyInfo file:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ConnectToAPI")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ConnectToAPI")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("f29d88e8-cd96-490a-8dc1-3bf68852a396")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

And the ClassLibrary:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConnectToAPI
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("41B3F5BC-A52B-4AED-90A0-F48BC8A391F1")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ISharconn
    {
        //Authentication
        string url { get; set; }
        string user { get; set; }
        string password { get; set; }
        string token { get; set; }
        dynamic stuff { get; set; }

        string upload { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }
        string expires_in { get; set; }
        string access_token { get; set; }
        string teamId { get; set; }

        //video object properties
        //**********************************
        string Path { get; set; }  //cambiar para que sea el path correcto
        int Size { get; set; }
        string ContentType { get; set; }
        string UserId { get; set; }
        int FolderId { get; set; }
        int QueueId { get; set; }
        string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }
        string ChaptersPath { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }

        List<ShareUsers> ShareUser { get; set; }
        List<TagsUpload> Tags { get; set; }
        List<CommentUpload> Comments { get; set; }
        List<DocumentUpload> Documents { get; set; }
        List<CommentUsers> UsersReceiveComments { get; set; }

        string StartConnection();
        void AddVideoTags(int tagId, string description);
        void AddShareUsers(string id, string username, bool allowDownload);
        void AddVideoComments(string commentText, bool status);
        void AddDocuments(string path, string ContentType, int Size);
        string GetTree(string url, string access_token);
        string UploadVideo(string url, string access_token);
        void AddUserListComments(string sendtoId, string sendtoUsername);
        void GetToken(string url, string userName, string password);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("20EBC3AF-22C6-47CE-B70C-7EBBA12D0A29")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("ConnectToAPI.Sharconn")]
    public class Sharconn : ISharconn
    {
        //Authentication
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        public string token { get; set; }
        public dynamic stuff { get; set; }

        public string upload { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }

        public string teamId { get; set; }

        //video object properties
        //**********************************
        public string Path { get; set; }  //cambiar para que sea el path correcto
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int FolderId { get; set; }
        public int  QueueId { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }
        public string ChaptersPath { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }     

        private List<ShareUsers> shareUser  = new List<ShareUsers>();
        public List<ShareUsers> ShareUser
        {
            set { shareUser = value; }
            get { return shareUser; }
        }


        private List<TagsUpload> tags = new List<TagsUpload>();
        public List<TagsUpload> Tags
        {
            set { tags = value; }
            get { return tags; }
        }

        private List<CommentUpload> comments = new List<CommentUpload>();
        public List<CommentUpload> Comments
        {
            set { comments = value; }
            get { return comments; }
        }

        private List<DocumentUpload> documents = new List<DocumentUpload>();
        public List<DocumentUpload> Documents
        {
            set { documents = value; }
            get { return documents; }
        }

        private List<CommentUsers> usersReceiveComments = new List<CommentUsers>();
        public List<CommentUsers> UsersReceiveComments
        {
            set { usersReceiveComments = value; }
            get { return usersReceiveComments; }
        }

        public string StartConnection() {

            upload = UploadVideo(url + "api/Videos/UploadVideo", access_token);

            //Access API controller
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);

            var response = client.GetAsync("api/data/authorize").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Success");
               // MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }
            string message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Trace.TraceInformation("URL response: " + message);
            //MessageBox.Show("URL response: " + message);
            return message;
        }


        public void GetToken(string url, string userName, string password)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                            {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", userName ),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "password", password )
                            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.PostAsync(url + "token", content).Result;

                string text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;       

                stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
                name = stuff.token_type;
                expires_in = stuff.expires_in;
                access_token = stuff.access_token;

            }
        }


        public void AddVideoTags(int tagId, string description)
        {
            TagsUpload tag = new TagsUpload();
            tag.TagId = tagId; 
            tag.TagDescription = description; 

            tags.Add(tag);            
        }


        public void AddShareUsers(string id, string username, bool allowDownload)
        {                   

            ShareUsers share = new ShareUsers(); //lista de usuarios a los que se le comparte el video
            share.Id = id; //id del usuario al que se le comparte
            share.Username = username; 
            share.AllowDownload = allowDownload; 
            share.NotificationPublic = false; //siempre en false
            share.NotificationComment = false; //siempre en false

            shareUser.Add(share);

        }

            public void AddUserListComments(string sendtoId, string sendtoUsername)
        {         
            CommentUsers users = new CommentUsers();  //usuario al que se le envía el comentario
            users.Id = sendtoId; 
            users.Username = sendtoUsername;

            usersReceiveComments.Add(users);


        }

        public void AddVideoComments(string commentText, bool status) { 

            CommentUpload c = new CommentUpload();
            c.CommentText = commentText; 
            c.Public = status; //false; 
            c.Receivers = usersReceiveComments;             
            comments.Add(c);
        }


        public void AddDocuments(string path, string ContentType, int Size)
        {
            DocumentUpload doc = new DocumentUpload();
            doc.Path = path;
            doc.ContentType = ContentType; 
            doc.Size = Size;

            documents.Add(doc);
        }


        public string GetTree(string url, string access_token)
        {
            //tree = GetTree(url + "api/Folders/GetTree", access_token);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);

                Team team = new Team();

                team.Id = teamId;

                var teamObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(team);

                var response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(teamObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

                //recibe el token desde el servidor
                string text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return text;

                //tree = text;
            }
        }

        public string UploadVideo(string url, string access_token)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);


                //***************************************
                //SET VIDEO VALUES
                //***************************************
                Video v = new Video();
                v.Path = Path; //cambiar para que sea el path correcto
                v.Size = Size; //tamaño en bytes del video
                v.ContentType = ContentType; // "video/mp4";
                v.UserId = UserId; //"b93232eb-6deb-4eae-b252-a633e1264f0f"; //usuario que sube el video
                v.FolderId = FolderId; //41; //Id de la carpeta en la que se guarda el video. Si es 0 entonces solo va al directorio raíz
                v.QueueId = QueueId;//0; //id del archivo en la cola de subida. Es 0 si nunca se pausó la descarga.
                v.ThumbnailPath = ThumbnailPath; // "C://VideoPrueba/presentacion icse/atencion1.jpg"; //path de la imagen de presentación del video. Thumbnail
                v.ChaptersPath = ChaptersPath; // "C://VideoPrueba/chapters.vtt"; //path de los episodios o capitulos del video en formato vtt
                v.Description = Description; // "Descripción de video";
                v.Name = Name; //nombre del video, si viene "" entonces se toma el nombre del archivo.

                v.Share = shareUser;
                v.Tags = tags;
                v.Comments = comments;
                v.Docs = documents;

                 //private List<ShareUsers> shareUser = new List<ShareUsers>();

                //private List<TagsUpload> _tags = new List<TagsUpload>();

                //private List<CommentUpload> _comments = new List<CommentUpload>();

                //private List<DocumentUpload> _documents = new List<DocumentUpload>(); //lista de docs a subir. (jpeg, pdf, etc)

                v.ErrorCode = 0; //codigo de error (su función se da solo en la respuesta). En la petición siempre es 0

                //return v;

                var videoObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);

                var response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(videoObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

                //recibe la respuesta que es un JSON con el objeto Video
                //Verificar el error_code. Si es 0 todo fue correcto, sino hubo un error
                string text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return text;
            }
        }        
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShareUsers
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool AllowDownload { get; set; }
        public bool NotificationPublic { get; set; }
        public bool NotificationComment { get; set; }
    }

    public class TagsUpload
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public string TagDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommentUpload
    {
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        public bool Public { get; set; }
        public List<CommentUsers> Receivers { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommentUsers
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocumentUpload
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Video
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int VideoId { get; set; }
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public List<ShareUsers> Share { get; set; }
        public int FolderId { get; set; }
        public List<TagsUpload> Tags { get; set; }
        public List<CommentUpload> Comments { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentUpload> Docs { get; set; }
        public int QueueId { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }
        public string ChaptersPath { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

VB6 code, it contais a reference to the Class Library created, I can see the methods and properties of DLL only in design time:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim connectToAp As New connectToApi.Sharconn

    connectToAp.url = "http://test.azurewebsites.net"
    connectToAp.user = "asas"
    connectToAp.password = "freng$"

    connectToAp.StartConnection


    'OBTENGO EL TOKEN Y SUS PROPIEDADES

    Call connectToAp.GetToken(connectToAp.url, connectToAp.user, connectToAp.password)

    Dim tokenName As String
    tokenName = connectToAp.Name

    Dim tokenExpires As String
    tokenExpires = connectToAp.expires_in

    Dim accessToken As String
    accessToken = connectToAp.access_token



    'VALORES DEL VIDEO

     Dim Path As String
     Path = connectToAp.Path

     Dim Size As Integer
     Size = connectToAp.Size

     Dim ContentType As String
     ContentType = connectToAp.ContentType


     Dim UserId As String
     UserId = connectToAp.UserId

     Dim FolderId As Integer
    FolderId = connectToAp.FolderId

    Dim QueueId As Integer
    QueueId = connectToAp.QueueId


     Dim ThumbnailPath As String
    ThumbnailPath = connectToAp.ThumbnailPath

     Dim ChaptersPath As String
    ChaptersPath = connectToAp.ChaptersPath


    'ANADE LOS TAGS AL VIDEO, ID MAS NOMBRE. SI EL ID ES 0 QUIERE DECIR QUE EL TAG ES NUEVO
    ' Y SE GUARDA EN LA BD DE TAGS EXISTENTES
    Dim tagId As Long
    Dim tagDescription As String
    Call connectToAp.AddVideoTags(tagId, tagDescription)

    'ANADE LOS USUARIOS A LOS QUE SE LE VA A COMPARTIR EL VIDEO
    Dim idUser As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim allowDownload As Boolean
    Call connectToAp.AddShareUsers(idUser, username, allowDownload)

    Dim commentText As String
    Dim isPublic As Boolean
    Call connectToAp.AddVideoComments(commentText, isPublic)

    Dim sendtoId As String
    Dim sendtoUsername As String
    Call connectToAp.AddUserListComments(sendtoId, sendtoUsername)
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveX objects were obsoleted (or a least attempted) by Microsoft back in 2005.  Did you try regsrv32?  See following webpage for help : http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4F811A9B23F1D46E862566F700615B7A

Comment: Don't use Regsvr32 on .NET assemblies.  You'll have to quote the *exact* command lines you used to give somebody a shot at guessing what could have gone wrong.  "to be caled from C#" is also very mysterious.

Comment: I just edited the title. about regsvr32 it says that cannot find the specified module. Not sure if there are some missing dependences. And the RegAsm command give a similar error: "Unable to locate input assembly"

Comment: Does your assembly need to be in the GAC?  I find it easier to use private assemblies for COM interop.